# React-native get all photos from Camera Roll and Camera Roll API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get camera roll photos using react native CameraRoll.getPhotos API. The issue I found that the documentation is not great. In [react-native official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html) there are two terms that were mentioned `getPhotosReturnChecker` and `getPhotosParamChecker` where I can get the detail about this parameters.

I found the following object that can be passed to `CameraRoll.getPhotos` from [bhwgroup blog](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/accessing-iphone-camera-roll-images-react-native)

```
{
    first: ..., // (required) The number of photos wanted in reverse order of the photo application
    after: ..., // A cursor returned from a previous call to 'getPhotos'
    groupTypes: ..., // Specifies which group types to filter the results to
                     // One of ['Album', 'All', 'Event', 'Faces', 'Library', 'PhotoStream', 'SavedPhotos'(default)]
    groupName: ..., // Specifies filter on group names, like 'Recent Photos' or custom album titles
    assetType: ... // Specifies filter on assetType
                   // One of ['All', 'Videos', 'Photos'(default)]
}
```

According to these it always require a parameter first which dictates how many pictures we can get from CameraRoll. Instead if I want all the photos from camera roll how can I get it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to do some paging to access all photos. Basically, you are loading them in chunks, and keeping track of the place where you left off after each fetch. You'll want a state similar to this:

```
this.state = {
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
  assets: [],
  lastCursor: null,
  noMorePhotos: false,
  loadingMore: false,
};
```

Then fetching functions similar to these. This example assumes you are using a `ListView` to display your photos using a `ListView.DataSource`

```
tryPhotoLoad() {
  if (!this.state.loadingMore) {
    this.setState({ loadingMore: true }, () => { this.loadPhotos(); });
  }
}

loadPhotos() {
  const fetchParams = {
    first: 35,
    groupTypes: 'SavedPhotos',
    assetType: 'Photos',
  };

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  // not supported in android
    delete fetchParams.groupTypes;
  }

  if (this.state.lastCursor) {
    fetchParams.after = this.state.lastCursor;
  }

  CameraRoll.getPhotos(fetchParams).then((data) => {
    this.appendAssets(data);
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
}

appendAssets(data) {
  const assets = data.edges;
  const nextState = {
    loadingMore: false,
  };

  if (!data.page_info.has_next_page) {
    nextState.noMorePhotos = true;
  }

  if (assets.length > 0) {
    nextState.lastCursor = data.page_info.end_cursor;
    nextState.assets = this.state.assets.concat(assets);
    nextState.dataSource = this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(
      _.chunk(nextState.assets, 3)
    );
  }

  this.setState(nextState);
}

endReached() {
  if (!this.state.noMorePhotos) {
    this.tryPhotoLoad();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if I can filter by 'Selfies' Album?

Comment: @Carol I'd checkout this library [`react-native-photos-framework`](https://github.com/olofd/react-native-photos-framework)